`ReferenceError: image is not defined` in React App
I'm getting this error ReferenceError: image is not defined even though the link works when I paste it into my browser.
Copy of the error from developer tools console:
ReferenceError: image is not defined
    at Card (card.jsx:6:42)

This is the component I created:
import styles from './card.module.css';

function Card(){
    return(
        <div className={styles.card}>
            <img className= {styles.card-image} src="https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nfl/players/full/4241479.png" alt="profile picture"></img>
            <h2 className={styles.card-title}>Patrick Mahomes</h2>
            <p className={styles.card-text}>Football player for the kansas city chiefs.</p>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Card

This is where I'm trying to import the component to make sure it works:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import _navbar from "../NavBar/navbar";
import Card from "../components/Card/card";

export default function _quarterbacksPage() {
    const quarterbacks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <_navbar />
            {quarterbacks.map((quarterback) => (
                <Link key={quarterback} to={`/quarterbacks/${quarterback}`}>
                    Quarterback {quarterback}
                </Link>
            ))}
            <Card />
            
        </div>
        </>
    );

}


Well that's where I'm confused because when I take the card component out my code works perfectly fine @Evert

Kanar's answer fixed it. I was following a tutorial and they weren't using brackets for the className.
